# Sort the data by month wise

Tags: ios, swift, sorting

I am using

```
 self.alldata = self.alldata?.sorted { $0.Edate < $1.Edate }
```

This above code gives me the data to sort by date wise. But how can I sort my data in month wise.Here is my full date response from server which I am populating in my table view

```
12-12-2017 09:12:45
```

How can i sort by month ?

Comment: What do you mean by month ? Just sorting by date should be enough. What about last year December dates should it be grouped with this year December dates? Are you trying to group it by sections where each section has only dates which are within the same month?

Comment: @david date itself sorting using day, month and year. So what do you want?

Comment: When u sort by date, it will get sorted by month too.

Comment: @Nirmalsinh Actually , my respose like `12-12-17, 12-12-17,12-12-17` measn in my table view i need to show like `12-12-17,12-12-17,12-12-17`..Does my above code will work

Comment: yeah, it will work.

Comment: Btw if you want to mutate the original array just use `sort` instead of `sorted`

Comment: @LeoDabus   mutate mean that ??

Comment: `alldata?.sort { $0.Edate < $1.Edate }`

Comment: Yes, but what will b done...by which wise it will sort

Comment: same as your code above which is a hack

Comment: Check the answer, two approaches considered.

Answer (score 1):

For these specific types of sorting you might want to split your `EDate` property into property-components and use composite sort descriptors (`NSSortDescriptor`). Sort descriptors may be useful especially if you plan to prioritize keys you want to sort your objects with. It allows you to introduce primary and secondary criteria for sorting, which is sometimes extremely useful.

Consider the following example:

### 1. Derive your object from NSObject and split date into components

```
class MyObject : NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var dateYear : Int
    @objc dynamic var dateMonth : Int
    @objc dynamic var dateDay : Int

    // add Hour or Weekday if needed

    init(dateYear: Int, dateMonth: Int, dateDay: Int) {
        self.dateYear = dateYear
        self.dateMonth = dateMonth
        self.dateDay = dateDay
    }
}
```

Here, `@objc dynamic` keywords are used to gain compatibility with Objective-C' `NSSortComparator`, which is based on KVC.

Define array as usual:

```
var objects : [MyObject] = [
    MyObject(dateYear: 2017, dateMonth: 12, dateDay: 7),
    MyObject(dateYear: 2017, dateMonth: 11, dateDay: 24),
    MyObject(dateYear: 2016, dateMonth: 5, dateDay: 9),
    MyObject(dateYear: 2016, dateMonth: 2, dateDay: 15),
    MyObject(dateYear: 2014, dateMonth: 7, dateDay: 13),
    MyObject(dateYear: 2016, dateMonth: 11, dateDay: 1)
]
```

### 2. Make sort descriptors and sort

```
var descriptor1 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateMonth", ascending: true)
var descriptor2 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "dateYear", ascending: true)
var sorted = (objects as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [descriptor1, descriptor2]) as! [MyObject]
```

### Output (month | year | day)

```
sorted.forEach {
    print($0.dateMonth, $0.dateYear, $0.dateDay)
}
```

_

```
2 2016 15
5 2016 9
7 2014 13
11 2016 1
11 2017 24
12 2017 7
```

Specifying multiple sort descriptors lets you prioritize sorting criteria. Firstly take into account month, arrange ascending, then if possible, arrange ascending by year, and leave day as it is. This is where sort descriptors are helpful.

**P.S** If you don't need these additional criteria and don't care about the secondary order, then just compare two month components:

```
func month(of date: Date) -> Int {
    return Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date)
}

var sorted = objects.sorted(by: {month(of: $0.Edate) > month(of: $1.Edate) })
```

**P.P.S** Same functionality as with `NSSortDescriptors` can well be reached by writing your own sorting algorithms with those nested `for` loops, but `NSSortDescriptor` is just handy.